# How do I add this Github project to ONE screen of my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, mobile, jar

I'm new to Android development and I want to add a chat screen to my app. I found [this project](https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms) on Github. I made a layout resource file called `chat_screen.xml` and I want to add the Github project's messaging screen to it. How do I do this?

Comment: Just download the project and open it as an android studio project. There doesn't seem to be any setup option in the project, just source code.

Answer (score 0):

Import the entire project from GitHub, then modify as you needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the entire project on github.

> File > New > Import Project

Hint: Just click default selection